# When doing foreach for Sharepoint 2010 UserProfiles, is there a way to sort them?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am making a simple birthday calendar webpart for Sharepoing 2010.

I need to iterate through all users of a site and show those who have birthday on said date. I need to present users in alphabetical order of their names.

I can iterate through user list by doing ilke this:

```
SPSite currentSite = ...
ServerContext ospServerContext = ServerContext.GetContext(currentSite);
UserProfileManager ospUserProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(ospServerContext);
foreach (UserProfile ospUserProfile in ospUserProfileManager) { ... }
```

However, then i have no control over the order of profiles. Is there any built in way to order the profiles by some simple rule, or do i have to make a Dictionary(string,UserProfile), fill it from UserProfileManager, then sort it by its key, and then do foreach for its members?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add using block:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Create a collection of user profiles:

```
var collection = new List<UserProfile>();
```

populate it:

```
foreach (UserProfile ospUserProfile in ospUserProfileManager) 
{ 
   collection.Add(ospUserProfile);
}
```

then [sort it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx):

```
var sorted = collection.OrderBy(p => p.PropertyToSort);
```

Comment: Hmm its strange but VS2010 complains about OrderBy being not a valid member of List<UserProfile>... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you're going to go down the LINQ route, you may as well go the whole hog and use `var collection = ospUserProfileManager.Cast<UserProfile>().ToList()` instead of a `foreach` loop or, better, go straight from the `Cast` into the `OrderBy` without making a `List`. And do the birthday-filtering `Where` before the `OrderBy` for efficiency...

Comment: *ToList()* waits an *IEnumerable<T>* source, but *ospUserProfileManager* does not inherit it.

Comment: My mistake, I assumed if you could call `foreach` on it you could call `Cast<>` to get a nicely typed enumerator.